# Ideal cities in future

Tags: environment, cities

Because of population growth, space for living will become a problem in the future. Either we could build lots of skyscrapers or we could build underground cities. And I think underground cities would help the world much more than skyscrapers.
While there may be many better designs than what I have in mind, I think the current cities are inadequately designed. There are many problems that the current cities are unable to face.

So I would like to hear your designs of ideal cities with current technology. Another question is while the current governments can't redesign cities on a whim, do they take action to build futuristic green cities?

Edited:
 It's true that many cities are not designed by architects and they do suffer from it. These cities are not green ( environmental friendly) cities. These cities have slums. And governments usually destroy and rebuild some parts of these cities due to lack of planning. Most of the problems could be avoided by planing them ahead.

Maybe free citizen's would not like living in 'ideal' cities. But we only have to use restrictions on buildings to create them. So I don't think people would be averse to the idea.

What is an ideal city? Ideal city has to be environmental friendly.  Ideal city should not suffer from over population. Ideal city should be able to withstand natural hazards. Ideal city while not completely self sufficient would be able to function clearly in a disaster without aids.

Comment: Note: Current cities are not "designed". They are the direct results of people moving to where they would rather be, not typically of a city architect. So an important question is, are we assuming that there is some particular entity centrally planning an entire city? Or is it, like an actual city, a spontaneous order resulting from individual human interactions? If the former, then you can plan away; if the latter, then you must take into account whether free peoples would actually do this or that.

Moreover, what "inadequacies" are you seeking to remedy?

Comment: Also, you might consider exactly what you mean by 'ideal'?  Who sets the standards?  From the point of view of the inhabitants, I find it hard to imagine that anyone forced to live in either a skyscraper or an underground prison would think their circumstances ideal.

Comment: @AjY *"Current cities are not "designed". They are the direct results of people moving to where they would rather be, not typically of a city architect."* In most cities of the world, every new building needs a construction permit. This gives the politics control over where what kind of buildings are allowed. Most cities are divided into specific zones where only specific buildings are allowed. So to a certain degree most cities **are** designed by architects.

Comment: Part 1:
That is true, but the city itself was not generated at the whim of those politicians. Moreover, such zoning rules can have caustic (or more often, one could argue, detrimental) results.
(1) There's a difference between saying this or that can or can't be in this particular area, and saying, "This place will be this and that."
(2) I happen to come from a region with its own plethora of cities, 6 of which are among the 15 fastest growing cities in the US, that has done a pretty great job with minimal zoning regulation. That place is called Texas.

Comment: Part 2:
(3) In heavily zoned cities, you'll often see an unusual quantity of housing issues.
(4) Cities that adopt the "planning" idea will often tend to have higher population density in themselves, due to a number of factors which make it more difficult for folks to move to the outskirts of town and still have a job in that city. There are many reasons automobiles were such a big deal: One was that it permitted people to spread out.
(5) Not all zoning is equal. There are very heavily zoned cities, and lightly zoned cities. Many have some zoning, but not all are of city-designing magnitudes.

Comment: @Philipp: In most cities of the world, however, those construction permits are available to anyone willing to sufficiently grease the palms of the officials in charge of granting them.  In the US, sufficiently well-greased palms can quite often get the developer massive public subsidies...

Comment: Re your edit about unplanned cities having slums, you might want to look into the history of housing projects, which are about as close to planned cities as you can find in real life.  Then ask yourself whether it's the city design that makes slums, or the people who live there.